# CustomView doesn't fill available space

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a view that will fill all the available space on the screen. Iv'e set my view's layout params to `match_parent` and used `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` when drew `Rect` on `Canvas` and it is still filling only about two thirds of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:beat_box="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.yotam.aprivate.demo.mybeatbox.Views.BeatBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    beat_box:my_color="5D32EA">
</com.yotam.aprivate.demo.mybeatbox.Views.BeatBox>
</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomView:

```
public class BeatBox extends View {
private int color;
private Context context;
private Paint paintBox = new Paint();
private Paint paintBackground = new Paint();

public BeatBox(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    color = getAttrColor(attrs);
    initDrawing();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), paintBackground); //this.getHeight() this.getWidth() also doesn't work
    paintBackground.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth() , getHeight(), Color.parseColor("#cb356b"), Color.parseColor("#bd3f32"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

[image: It doesn't fill the whole layout, I want it to fill the white area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have inversed the width and height in this line :

```
canvas.drawRect(0,0, canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(), paintBackground);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters of `drawRect()` method are as below:

```
drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

You have used `canvas.getHeight()` as `right` and `canvas.getWidth()` as `bottom`, that's why the `height` of `custom view` is same as device `width`.

**SOLUTION:**

You should use `canvas.getWidth()` as `right` and `canvas.getHeight()` as `bottom`

**Update `onDraw()` method as below:**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paintBackground); 
    paintBackground.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth() , getHeight(), Color.parseColor("#cb356b"), Color.parseColor("#bd3f32"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Hope this will help~